# RadioButton checked programmatically won't uncheck

Tags: android, radio-button, radio-group

I have these RadioButtons set up within a RadioGroup:

```
<RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioGroupLeakTight"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

  <RadioButton
               android:text="@string/action_yes"
               android:id="@+id/radioLeakTightYes"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

  <RadioButton
               android:text="@string/action_no"
               android:id="@+id/radioLeakTightNo"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RadioGroup>
```

With the code below I try to toggle one of the RadioButtons through code:

```
radioGroupLeakTight.check((currentTask.isLeakTight() ? R.id.radioLeakTightYes : R.id.radioLeakTightNo));
```

If I don't use the above code the RadioButtons work as intended: whenever one gets checked, the other one gets unchecked. If I use the code to pre-check one of the RadioButtons this functionality gets lost. Whenever I try to check a RadioButton the other one remains checked.

I've read solutions where I should implement the '`OnCheckedChangeListener`' and toggle them myself. But I guess that's just covering up something else that doesn't work, no? I've also read people that had these issues, but they had the RadioGroup missing, which I clearly have.

What am I doing wrong? Is the only solution really implementing '`OnCheckedChangeListener`' and toggling the other RadioButtons myself?

**UPDATE 08/12/2016:**

So I've continued my search and implemented '`OnCheckedChanged`'. What I see now is that whenever I check one of the RadioButtons this event is never fired. The listener is set on the 2 RadioGroups. 
I'm starting to suspect these RadioButtons lose their membership to the RadioGroup? Whenever I check them through code (after I set my listeners) the event is fired successfully.

Answer (score 2):

Use `clearCheck()` for RadioGroups. [Learn more](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html#clearCheck()).
If you need to check another RadioButton, you can do so after this.

> Whenever I try to check a RadioButton, the other one remains checked.

```
RadioButton radioLeakTightYes = (RadioButton) findViewById(...);
RadioButton radioLeakTightNo = (RadioButton) findViewById(...);

radioGroupLeakTight.clearCheck();
if(currentTask.isLeakTight()){
    radioGroupLeakTight.check(radioLeakTightYes.getId());
} else {
    radioGroupLeakTight.check(radioLeakTightNo.getId());
}
```

Comment: Using clearCheck indicates that I should implement the listener. Is that really the only way?

Comment: the edit will give you an idea of what I meant. Does this apply?

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe my question was not clear enough. I know how I can clear and toggle the RadioButtons through code. But after I check one of them programatically, the auto-toggling functionality gets lost when a user tries to use it. Both values will be checked then.

Comment: yep, right. So, you should use the listener. You can `clearCheck()` and enable another RadioButton in `OnCheckedChangeListener`.